# How to handle the birth and death of particle without reading from the buffer

Tags: opengl, glsl

I've implemented a simple particle system where each particle has a position, velocity, age and lifespan stored in different SSBOs.

Most of the data including all the position, velocity and age is updated through a compute shader. And emiting new particles is handled by CPU since it's a serial process. But in order to track whether each particle is alive or dead, I have to read all the lifespan data back to CPU from the SSBO (using glGetBufferSubData()), which do stalls the GPU I'm afraid.

So I was wondering is there any way to prevent reading the data back from GPU. I found a demo particle system made by AMD using directX, which uses a dead list and an alive list in the compute shader. But I have no idea how to achieve this with GLSL. Any ideas?

Demo code:

```
...

// The dead list, so any particles that are retired this frame can be added to this list
AppendStructuredBuffer<uint>            g_DeadListToAddTo       : register( u2 );

// The alive list which gets built using this shader
RWStructuredBuffer<float2>              g_IndexBuffer           : register( u3 );

...

// Dead particles are added to the dead list for recycling
if ( pb.m_Age <= 0.0f || killParticle )
{
    pb.m_Age = -1;
    g_DeadListToAddTo.Append( id.x );
}

...
```